# How to copy data from one table to another new table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, copy

I want to copy data from one table to another in MySQL.

Table 1 (Existing table):

```
aid    
st_id
from_uid
to_gid
to_uid
created
changed
subject
message
link
```

Table 2 (New Table)

```
st_id
uid
changed
status
assign_status
```

I want to copy some fields of data from TABLE 1 into TABLE 2.

Can this be done using MySQL queries?

Comment: Is this a one time job or you plan to do it regularly?

Comment: @@jdias: until now it's one time job..

Comment: @jdias To clarify, if it's not a one time job, what should a MySQL noob look into doing instead?

Comment: Probably views to avoid duplicating data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy data into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table)

Answer (score 345, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (st_id,uid,changed,status,assign_status)
SELECT st_id,from_uid,now(),'Pending','Assigned'
FROM table1
```

If you want to include all rows from table1. Otherwise you can add a `WHERE` statement to the end if you want to add only a subset of `table1`.

Comment: Great, glad to see this is the same as what I've been used to in T-SQL.

Comment: If You want to copy all table1 data then you must create new table2 before copy @SANDEEP

Answer (score 106):

If you don't want to list the fields, and the structure of the tables is the same, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT * FROM `table1`;
```

or if you want to create a new table with the same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

[Reference for insert select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html); 
[Reference for create table select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: why `[AS]` is in square brackets, what is done by `AS` in here

Comment: It denotes that the word is optional.  It is written that way because I copied and pasted from the docs; it does not add anything.
I think the `AS` is mandatory in other SQL dialects.

Comment: The bracket should be removed for it to perform the task

Answer (score 23):

You can easily get data from another table. You have to add fields  only you want.

The mysql query is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name1(fields you want)
  SELECT fields you want FROM table_name2
```

where, the values are copied from table2 to table1

Answer (score 20):

```
CREATE TABLE newTable LIKE oldTable;
```

Then, to copy the data over

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable;
```

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to use INSERT...SELECT statement in mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Intuitive :) I like it. It is a normal SELECT statement, preceded with one line of "INSERT INTO".

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: Doesn't work.  Per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html), "MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension"

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Column1,Column2..) SELECT Column1,Column2.. FROM Table2 [WHERE <condition>]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

You should create table2 first.

```
insert into table2(field1,field2,...)
select field1,field2,....
from table1
where condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

the above query only works if we have created clients table with matching columns of the customer

```
INSERT INTO clients(c_id,name,address)SELECT c_id,name,address FROM customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
insert into #temp 
select Product_ID,Max(Grand_Total) AS 'Sales_Amt', Max(Rec_Amount) ,'',''
from Table_Name group by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the table is existed. you can try 
insert into table_name select * from old_tale;

IF the table is not existed. you should try 
create table table_name like old_table;
insert into table_name select * from old_tale;

Answer (score 0):

$sql_query= "REPLACE INTO customerdeletelist SELECT * FROM customerdetail WHERE account_number = '$account_number' &&          customer_number = '$customer_number' && updateDate = '$updateDate'";

$shift= mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If someone doing it regularly - u can try to use this tool. Unstable, but ready https://github.com/morkva-vladyslav/database-donor

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32984250)