# Perl Inter-Database Transfer

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I'm trying to select data from MySQL table StoreEvent and insert it into StoreEvent2 using DBI module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:db_m2','root','rootboot')
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from StoreEvent limit 10");
$sth->execute
or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print "@row\n";
}
```

and output as follows:

```
# ./perl_data_dumper.pl
26152 2 1366735974109 1366735982127 9510 0
26153 2 1366735974614 1366735982639 9510 0
26154 2 1366735974613 1366735982637 9510 0
26155 2 1366735974614 1366735982639 9510 0
26156 2 1366735975621 1366735983642 9510 0
26157 2 1366735975621 1366735983643 9510 0
26158 2 1366735977133 1366735985160 9510 0
26159 2 1366735977134 1366735985164 9510 0
26160 2 1366735977637 1366735985659 9510 0
26161 2 1366735977639 1366735985673 9510 0
```

I'm not really sure how I can go about getting the results from first query and insert it into the other table.

here is what I have tried

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:db_m2','root','root')
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from StoreEvent limit 10");
$sth->execute
or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print "@row\n";
}

$dbh2 = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:db_m2','root','root')
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sth2 = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO StoreEvent2      (StoreID,StoreType,EventStart,EventEnd,AppserverID,Number") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) );
$sth2->execute
or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print "@row\n";
}
```

Its not really working right, I wonder if someone can give me some insight.

Thank you

Comment: See this SO post: [How to copy data from one table to another new table in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482443/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-new-table-in-mysql)

Comment: Comments about your DBI usage: 1) You don't need two handles to the same database. Call `connect` once and reuse the handle in subsequent queries. 2) If you set the [`RaiseError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) option to `connect`, your program will automatically die on error, so you don't have to put `or die ...` after every database action: `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { RaiseError => 1 });`

Comment: And don't call `fetch_*` for non-`SELECT` statements. `execute` will return the number of rows affected for a non-`SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

A few things

- `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  use them, always.
- If those tables are on the same database, just reuse the database handle.
- You aren't actually attempting to insert anything in your first loop, and your second loop is just bogus.

Cleaned up:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:db_m2','root','root')
    or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from StoreEvent limit 10");
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sth2 = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO StoreEvent2 (StoreID,StoreType,EventStart,EventEnd,AppserverID,Number") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) );

while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "@row\n";
    $sth2->execute(@row) or die $dbh->errstr;
}
```

Note this code is still fragile for a couple reasons though:

- You aren't specifying which columns you want from StoreEvent, but instead relying on `*`

  - There might be more columns than your attempting to INSERT into StoreEvent2, either now or at some later time if the table is altered.
  - The columns might be pulled in an order different than you're specifying in StoreEvent2
- You're inserting based on a possible primary key (StoreID) without checking to see if the record already exists.

Comment: Your query is pretty inefficient since MySQL provides [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes it potentially is, but there were enough other potential issues that I wanted to address that efficiency was not my primary concern.  User should understand the brute force method and its pitfalls before jumping to a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Miller [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819584/176646) a number of issues with your code. I'd like to add that you can do this in a single query, using MySQL's [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:db_m2', 'root', 'root', { RaiseError => 1 });

my $statement = <<'STATEMENT';
    INSERT INTO StoreEvent2 (StoreID, StoreType, EventStart, EventEnd, AppserverID, Number)
      SELECT StoreEvent.StoreID, StoreEvent.StoreType, StoreEvent.EventStart, StoreEvent.EventEnd, StoreEvent.AppserverID, StoreEvent.Number
      FROM StoreEvent
STATEMENT

my $rows = $dbh->do($statement);
say "Inserted $rows rows";

$dbh->disconnect;
```

I made the assumption that the column names are the same in both of your tables, but you can adjust the query if they aren't. Additional notes:

- If you change the `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE`, rows that would cause duplicate-key violations are ignored.
- The query above copies *all* rows in the first table. You can limit the rows to be copied by specifying a `WHERE` clause. I wouldn't use `LIMIT` by itself as you did in your original code, since that just grabs a random set of rows.
- Setting [`RaiseError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) in `connect` causes an exception to be raised when there are errors, so you don't have to add `or die ...` after each database action.
- If you will run this query multiple times in your program, use `prepare` and `execute` instead of `do`.