# Insert into two tables from one table (select)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, insert-into

I want to insert one record in each table from one select.

For example, insert in table "messages" and table "notifications" from table "users".

"notifications" need the LAST_INSERT_ID() to point to the message.

I can achieve one table like:

```
INSERT INTO message (`data1`, `data2`) SELECT "text", u.id FROM users u WHERE 1;
```

But don't know where to put the INSERT INTO for "notifications".

Comment: If you are looking for to have an atomic operation (Insert the information in both tables or nothing), you should use a transaction. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Execute the first insert, pull the last inserted id from that, then run the second insert with that ID. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Check this, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482443/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-new-table-in-mysql

Comment: @CrApHeR I tried this but the select just inserted one record in both tables, the select from the "users" table return about 10 rows for example, then the transaction should insert 10 rows in "messages" and 10 rows in "notifications", can I use the transaction for something like that? still I learned some now. Thanks!

Comment: @Elyor I think is the same script I got, I'm missing the part to insert to another table with the same select. Thanks.

Comment: @CrApHeR to expand my test this is what I did:
`START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @U_ID:=u.id FROM users u WHERE 1;
INSERT INTO message ('data1', 'data2') VALUES ("text", @U_ID);
INSERT INTO notificacion ('data1', 'data2') VALUES (@E_ID, LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;`

Comment: Some interesting approaches can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: @Axalix I understand now I can't insert with one SQL command, but a transaction works for me as CrApHeR example, how can I make the SELECT work with TRANSACTION for multiple inserting?