# MySQL: How to copy table A's data to new non-existing table B?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Update:**
In similar questions in SO,the table in which data was to be copied was already created unlike this case.

I have table *A* with few records and want its data copied to another non-existing table *B*. Looking for some query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy data from one table to another new table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482443/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-new-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like using `CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT * FROM A` because that won't capture:

- indexes
- constraints like PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE KEY, or FOREIGN KEY
- table options like ROW_FORMAT

At least it captures column-level options like NOT NULL and DEFAULT.

```
mysql> create table A ( i int primary key, x int default 123, unique key (x)) row_format=compressed;

mysql> create table b1 as select * from A;

mysql> show create table b1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: b1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `b1` (
  `i` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT '123'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

It did get the ENGINE and DEFAULT CHARSET table options, only because those are the global defaults. If I had non-default choices for either of those table options, they'd be lost in the clone table.

Try doing it in two steps like this:

```
CREATE TABLE B LIKE A;
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A;
```

The table B will have truly identical definition as table A, including indexes, constraints, and table options.

```
mysql> create table b2 like A;

mysql> show create table b2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: b2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `b2` (
  `i` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT '123',
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`),
  UNIQUE KEY `x` (`x`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to create a table as well as copy data in it in a single SQL query.

```
CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT * FROM A;
```

Working Example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da26e1/1