# Copy data from one table to another table in Postgres which contains many Columns

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I want to copy data from Table A to Table B in Postgres. Table A contains 40 columns and Table B contains 20 columns. It's like Table B is the subset of Table A, which means - Table B contains only some columns which are in Table A.

I have found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7483174/12556735 for copying the data if there are less number of columns.

Since there are many columns , is there any way in which we can copy data without mentioning the Column names?

Comment: Without mentioning the column names I'm afraid there is no way of PostgreSQL knowing which data you want to copy to other tables.

Comment: If B is a subset of A why do you need B at all?

Comment: The question is not about "WHY" but about "HOW". My problem is very broad and I asked it in a simplified manner.

Comment: 'is there any way in which we can copy data without mentioning the Column names?' - no

Answer (score 0):

**Choice 1:**
If you notice, your referred question / answer **itself answers your question** as does not have any limitation on the number of columns. But you should know the original column definition and the required column list. It can run well for many columns.

**Choice 2:**
If the columns are unknown, you shall try using

```
create table 'newtable' as (select * from 'existingtable');
```

**Choice 3:**
If the columns are unknown and you wanted to create a new table with selected columns ! (which means you should know about columns), you shall try

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema= 'yourdatabase' and table_name= 'yourtable';
```

And among the columns list, you shall use column_name, column_type, is_nullable, etc can be used on your script.