# Oracle PL/SQL: Copy data between tables given in variables

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables given with variables:

```
SOURCE_TABLE_NAME STRING(10) := 'TABLE1';
TARGET_TABLE_NAME STRING(10) := 'TABLE2';
```

I need to write a stored procedure at Oracle 12 PL/SQL to copy some rows from `SOURCE_TABLE_NAME` to `TARGET_TABLE_NAME`.

Which way is it better to use?

- CURSOR
- SYS_REFCURSOR
- Any other ways?

Comment: I mean to copy some rows between 2 existing TABLES in the database

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hnRNqtMdST8QKBG7ihSe2p/0

. You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237661/3654837, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7483174/3654837

Comment: Thank you, good idea. May I be sure that columns and values are related properly between 2 tables?

Comment: `INSERT INTO SELECT` copies data from one table to another table **AND** requires that data types in source and target tables match. You can try using `CAST` if the data types differ.

Comment: It does match. 2 tables have absolutely the same columns (don't ask me why I'm not using VIEWs). `INSERT INTO` works when I define columns like: `INSERT INTO table2(col1) SELECT col1 FROM table1`. But in my case I don't have list of columns in advance.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work in my case because of different columns order in the tables. I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any list of columns in advance but have absolutely same columns, you could use:

`INSERT INTO table_name_to_go SELECT * FROM initial_table_name;`

If they have different columns order you need to redefine them in your `SELECT` example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name_to_go -- column order: C1,C3,C2 and initial table order: C1,C2,C3
SELECT C1, C3, C2 FROM initial_table_name;
```

**<kbd>[Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pewExVafJT5awhr7cQri9X/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Yeah, it looks good. I need to check that columns order in both tables is the same.